# How to generate report

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports-8.5

I have problem in generate report. I use crystal report 8.5 with vb.net 2008,what I want is when I generate report it will appear red value, if the value is more or less than actual value else it will give default value but when I put this code it give me wrong result

```
If {Intake.wheatType} = {Spec.WheatType} AND
{Intake.HB43} >={Spec.M_Min} AND{Intake.HB43} >={Spec.M_Max} Then
Red
Else
DefaultAttribute
```

this report is related with two tables, which is table Spec and table Intake. Could anyone help/teach me how to fix this problem

Answer (score 0):

When determining whether a value is between a minimum and maximum, the logic will be:

Is the value **greater than** the minimum **and** is the value **less than** the maximum?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can create a `Formula Field` for that,

1. From `Field Explorer`, right click `Formula Field`
2. A popup window will appear, type the name of the formula you want.
3. in the `Formula Editor` insert you custome formula

Code:

```
If {Intake.wheatType} = {Spec.WheatType} AND {Intake.HB43} >={Spec.M_Min} AND {Intake.HB43} >={Spec.M_Max} Then
   Red
Else
   DefaultAttribute
```

Then click `OK`. Drag the newly created field on your report. And that's it.

**[For more info, see this: Adding Formula Field](http://vb.net-informations.com/crystal-report/vb.net_crystal_report_formula_fields.htm)**